# Using FOR XML PATH based on column values

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, for-xml-path

Based on the following DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE #Records
(
    ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    ResourceKey VARCHAR(500),
    [Value] VARCHAR(500)
)

INSERT INTO #Records ([ResourceKey], [Value])
VALUES 
('Root/Person/Age', '30'),
('Root/Person/Gender', 'Male'),
('Root/Person/Education/ElementarySchool', 'Sunnyside'),
('Root/Person/Education/HighSchool', 'Green Acres')
```

Is there any way, using FOR XML (or any other approach), to generate the following output?

```
<Root>
    <Person>
        <Age>30</Age>
        <Gender>Male</Gender>
        <Education>
            <ElementarySchool>Sunnyside</ElementarySchool>
            <HighSchool>Green Acres</HighSchool>
        </Education>
    </Person>
</Root>
```

I know that the following query would work for a specific node, but clearly wouldn't work for multiple nodes:

```
SELECT
    [Value] AS "Root/Person/Age"
FROM #Records
WHERE ID = 1
FOR XML PATH('')
```

NOTE - I am okay with a solution that involves iterating through each row one at a time, and inserting them into an XML doc. I briefly considered the `insert` XML DDL statement, however, I'm unfamiliar with how XML docs in SQL Server work, so I don't know exactly how I would formulate it, syntactically.

**EDIT**

To clarify, `ResourceKey` values are guaranteed to be unique. The example data is just to simplify constructing the query. Practically speaking, the table holds localization strings, which we need to convert to the listed XML format.

Comment: I'm aware of that, Dale. This is a one-off script that I need just for data migration purposes. It's not intended for long-term use, and performance is not a priority. Goal right now is just to get the data migrated.

Comment: how should such hypothetical script handle more than one "entity". Your sample data doesn't seem to contain any sort of ID to bind the entities together

Comment: In this situation there is only a single entity. The actual scenario isn't involving a person, I just used that to simplify constructing an example DDL. `ResourceKey` entries are guaranteed to be unique.

Comment: Is there a definitive list of possible node names?

Comment: @Charlieface unfortunately no, there is not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you can do something like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE #Records
(
    ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    ResourceKey VARCHAR(500),
    [Value] VARCHAR(500)
)

INSERT INTO #Records ([ResourceKey], [Value])
VALUES 
('Root/Person/Age', '30'),
('Root/Person/Gender', 'Male'),
('Root/Person/Education/ElementarySchool', 'Sunnyside'),
('Root/Person/Education/HighSchool', 'Green Acres')

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT  @SQL = stuff(
(
        SELECT  ',max(case when resourcekey = ' + QUOTENAME(resourcekey, '''') + ' then Value end) AS ' + QUOTENAME(resourcekey, '''')
        FROM    #Records
        FOR xml path(''), type).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)')
        , 1, 1, '')

SET @SQL = 'select ' + @SQL + ' from #records for xml path(''''),type'
EXEC    (@SQL)
```

This builds your query by gathering all the resource keys and doing a little conditional aggregation to get the field values.

Just for kicks i used FOR XML to concatenate strings instead of more modern STRING_AGG.

If your resourcekey is a very long string, you can replace QUOTENAMEs with `'''' + REPLACE(resourcekey, '''', '''''') + ''''`

Comment: This looks like exactly what I need. Let me run some tests to validate it works properly against a larger set of data. Thank you!

Comment: Amazing. Works perfectly. Only minor tweak I needed to make was to add an `ORDER BY` clause to the query that generated the records before running your code, since otherwise it was creating the same parent node multiple times if it encountered it in a disjoint manner.